# Contact Form - Html and Javascript includable just in html (tumblr)

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, tumblr

I'm trying to include a contact form in my tumblr blog (i use it as portfolio). The point is I already have the html and css for the form BUT I'm not being able to make the  part work. Mainly beacuse I can't refer to the .js file. I mean, i need the code on .js file to be included in that html so it does work.

Maybe there is another way to make this easier, but i'm not finding anyway to do it.

Here's the form html:

```
    <form id="c_form" name="contact">
        <div>
          <label>
            <p>Name</p>
            <input name="nombre" id="c_name" type="text" class="c_input" placeholder="..."/>
          </label>
          <br/>
          <label>
            <p>Email:</p>
            <input name="email"  id="c_mail" type="text" class="c_input" placeholder="..."/>
          </label>
        </div>
        <label>
          <p>Content:</p>
          <textarea name="mensaje"  id="c_msg" placeholder="..."></textarea>
        </label>

        <div id="c_btns">
            <input name="send" onclick="cargaSendMail()" type="button" value="Enviar" class="btn-b" id="c_enviar"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Heres the css:

```
.Contact {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/jxap4PO.jpg);
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}


.Contact p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Contact label p{
    color: #ee3333;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    margin:5px 0;
    font-size:1.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contactform{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color: #ee3333;
}

.c_input{
    padding: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    outline:1px solid #ee3333;
}

#c_form{
    margin: 25px;
    width: 90%;

}

#c_form textarea {
    outline:1px solid #ee3333;
}

.c_input, #c_form textarea{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 4px;
    background: transparent;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus{
    outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-style:italic; }
::-moz-placeholder { font-style:italic; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { font-style:italic; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { font-style:italic; }

#c_form textarea{
    min-height: 150px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#c_enviar{
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

#bottom_container{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#c_information{
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.c_error{
    color: #D64242;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.hide{
display:none;
}

.btn-b {
    width:100%;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #111111;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #cc0c0c #cc0c0c #cc0c0c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #ee3333;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ee3333 0%, #ee2222 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ee3333), color-stop(100%,#ee2222));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ee3333 0%,#ee2222 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ee3333 0%,#ee2222 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ee3333 0%,#ee2222 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ee3333 0%,#ee2222 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ee3333', endColorstr='#ee2222',GradientType=0 );
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-b:hover {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #cc0c0c #cc0c0c #cc0c0c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background: #da1b1b;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #da1b1b 0%, #b40f0f 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#da1b1b), color-stop(100%,#b40f0f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #da1b1b 0%,#b40f0f 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #da1b1b 0%,#b40f0f 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #da1b1b 0%,#b40f0f 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #da1b1b 0%,#b40f0f 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#da1b1b', endColorstr='#b40f0f',GradientType=0 );

}

.btn-b:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-b:active {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3282D3;
    border-color: #154C8C #154C8C #0E408E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px #1657B5 inset, 0 1px 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #2361A4;
}
```

If i'm right i should add a:

```
<script type='text/javascript' ......(code)></script>
```

And this is what will make the form work, but i dont know what that code should be.

Probably i'm missing smth but its my first time working with js i've just worked with html and css...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the `cargaSendMail()` function defined?

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways you could do this.  First of all, do you have a form proccessor?  If not, I recommend [allforms](http://allforms.mailjol.net).  They have a free account that your form can be sent to.  It proccesses the inputs and emails the results to you for free.

Try this for your javascript:

```
function cargaSendMail(){

var nombre = document.forms["contact"]["nombre"].value;
var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
var mensaje = document.forms["contact"]["mensaje"].value;

// The following "ifs" make sure that the user has filled out all fields.

if (nombre == null || nombre == ""){

alert("Please enter your name"); // Alert the user if he has not entered his name.
return false; // Stop running this function if the user has not entered his name.
}
if (email == null || email == ""){

alert("Please enter your email");
return false;
}
if (mensaje == null || mensaje == ""){

alert("Please enter your mensaje");
return false;
}

document.forms["contact"].submit(); 
/* If all fields are filled out, they code will not "return false" 
and will submit the form. */

}
```

Remember that this JS will do nothing unless you specify the form "action" attribute.  The url that you put in the "action" attribute of your form will be where the form information is processed.  If you use allforms, they will give you the url, and other instructions to get it working.  If I need to explain with more detail, let me know.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome @MazrimTaim!  Accept answer please if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could sign up for [mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) and use [their api](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/).

Check out [this jquery contact form](http://codepen.io/webcane/pen/LBspI) that submits via JSON. I use this method on my site.

```js
jQuery(function($)  
{
    $("#contact_form").submit(function()
    {
        var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
        var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
        var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
            data: {
                'key': 'sVRLFidC1A7K56TuUkyUQg',
                'message': {
                    'from_email': email,
                    'from_name': name,
                    'headers': {
                        'Reply-To': email
                    },
                    'subject': 'Website Contact Form Submission',
                    'text': msg,
                    'to': [
                    {
                        'email': 'riyadh@bscheme.com',
                        'name': 'Riyadh Al Nur',
                        'type': 'to'
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert('Your message has been sent. Thank you!'); // show success message
            $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            alert('Error sending message.');
        });
        return false; // prevent page refresh
    });
});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Contact Us</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name here" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address here" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="msg">Message</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="msg" name="msg" cols="6" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then just add the javascript below the html you posted above.

Comment: Nice idea, but having your mandril credentials free for anyone to (ab)use seems dangerous

Comment: agreed. it's mentioned in the docs, but if you want an entirely JS solution you don't have much choice...